# vcloud sdk API VApp.undeploy((UndeployPowerActionType.DEFAULT) gives intermittent exception

Tags: java, jaxb, vcloud-director-rest-api

We are calling the API to undeploy vApps, during out of hours periods, only to start them up again afterwards.

I get an intermittent error whilst trying to undeploy VApps. (I will give the full stack trace later).

Just to let you know what I am doing, is that I am calling VApp.shutdown() first, which always seems to return success. I sometimes wait a period of upto 10 minutes, before calling the Vapp.undeploy(UndeployPowerActionType.DEFAULT) call. It still more often than not, doesnt work. When I then run it again, it quite often DOES work (and when I check the result, the Vapp is indeed undeployed), or if it still doesn't work, then when I call it again, it does work.

The stack trace looks like the following.. (sometimes the array index is out of range with different numbers, eg -5 or -12 etc etc. Bu the stack trace always looks like the following...)

2014-07-17 13:10:33 ERROR [main] ControlModule:75 - Undeploying resulted in an error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -2
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.CollisionCheckStack.findDuplicate(CollisionCheckStack.java:133)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.CollisionCheckStack.push(CollisionCheckStack.java:71)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.pushObject(XMLSerializer.java:494)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:609)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:113)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:120)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:149)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:269)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:35)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:472)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:301)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:230)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:106)
        at com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.JAXBUtil.marshal(JAXBUtil.java:199)
        at com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.AbstractVapp.createVappUnDeployParamBody(AbstractVapp.java:299)
        at com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.AbstractVapp.undeploy(AbstractVapp.java:318)
        at com.ipt.ebsa.skyscape.client.module.ControlModule.controlVApp(ControlModule.java:70)
        at com.ipt.ebsa.skyscape.client.manager.VMManager.controlVApp(VMManager.java:294)
        at com.ipt.ebsa.skyscape.client.CloudManager.UndeployVApp(CloudManager.java:197)
        at com.ipt.ebsa.skyscape.client.RajVAppTest.stopAndUndeployVApp(RajVAppTest.java:178)
        at com.ipt.ebsa.skyscape.client.RajVAppTest.testUndeployVApp0(RajVAppTest.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
2014-07-17 13:10:33 DEBUG [main] ControlModule:77 - Undeploying of vapp 'TEST_RAJ2' complete
2014-07-17 13:10:33 DEBUG [main] VMManager:296 - controlVApp exit

Can someone tell me if I am doing anything wrong? Is it normal practise to just have to retry, and eventually it will work, in order to undeploy my Vapp.

If that is the case, and I do have to keep retrying, I can detect this exception, and if I get it, rety a certain number of times before failing finally and giving up?

Or is there another way to detect whether the Vapp is undeployed or not?

Would calling 'shutdown() rather than undeploy() work better? I think , in my experience, that seems more consistent. However, the resulting vApps in the console are entitled as 'partially running' rather than 'shutdown'. This may well be acceptable, as at the end of the day, we just want our cloud hosting partner to stop charging us for periods when we are not needing the vAPPs. I think shutting down the vAPP might actually achieve this purpose? I would have to check iwth the cloud hosting partner.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: It is certainly normal practice for us to have to retry all operations performed through the SDK whether in our on-premise vCloud or through their OnDemand offering.